# var schemaAttributes = this.waterline.schema[this.identity].attributes ** Waterline 0.10.0 - Sails v0.9.16

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

Hello I'm really new in Sails and Nodejs,

Im using mysql as a DB.

I got this error

> var schemaAttributes = this.waterline.schema[this.identity].attributes;
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of undefined

and I tried reinstalling the module (Waterline), reinstalling Sails and it still not working.

This is my adapter:

```
module.exports.adapters = {
    'default': 'mysql',
    disk: {
    module: 'sails-disk'
},

    mysql: {
        module: 'sails-mysql',
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        port: '3306',
        password: '**********', 
        database: '**********'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access what are essentially private APIs, so it's not surprising that you're not getting the results you want.  If you want to get the list of attributes of a model, simply do:

```
Model.attributes
```

or, if you need to determine the model name at runtime:

```
sails.models[modelName].attributes
```